# Why .Net textboxes have TextLength vs Text.Length?

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

Why do TextBoxes have a TextLength property? Does it offer any advantages over getting the Text's Length through Text.Length?

Comment: What kind of text box are you referring to?  WPF? Windows Forms?

Comment: @John Presumably WinForms since that's the one that actually has `TextLength` property.

Comment: I should have specified, but yes, WinForms.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Behind this WinForms control is a Win32 edit control.

The Win32 edit control exposes its text through the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT` messages.  You need to send `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` first so that you know how big a buffer to allocate.  Then you can send `WM_GETTEXT` to populate the buffer.

If you just want the length of the text you can obtain it without allocating a buffer by sending just the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message.

The .net control is simply reflecting this underlying control's behaviour. For a multi-line control with a lot of text, being able to obtain the text length without having to allocate and populate the buffer could be a very useful for performance.

Comment: Where can I go to find information like this? The .Net documentation doesn't go into this level of detail.

Comment: @Corey This sort of knowledge is only really gained by programming against the Win32 API. It's hard to get it when working with WinForms. Although you can program the Win32 API from .net it's messy. I personally learnt all my Win32 through the Delphi VCL and have zero experience of C#, .net, WinForms etc.